# how to ignore pushState history and go back to last page on back button

Tags: jquery, html, browser-history, pushstate

I am changing the `location.hash` as a user goes through a slideshow. So each slide has its own hash.

I would like to make the back button go to the previous page and not the previous hash. What is the best way to go about that?

Note: The previous page isnt always the same.

Comment: Are you actually using `pushState`, or just changing the hash?

Comment: I am using pushState since I do not support IE7. I could 'just change the hash' if that helps here.

Comment: Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FQXm7/12/show/ (to see code http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/FQXm7/12/) so you can use window.location = 'url-of-prev-page' in the code. This is not the only way :P I am sure but at least you can detect that user clicked the back button and you can navigate anywhere you want.